# WKWebView Request permission for DeviceMotion and DeviceOrientation is called every time app launches

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios13

Is there a way to only request DeviceMotion and DeviceOrientation permissions once, not every time the app launches. 
I am requesting permissions using

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)")
```

and

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)")
```

So is there a way to always grant permissions ?

Comment: App launches mean? when your app comes from background to foreground or when you open your app from the terminated or closed state?

Comment: Terminated or closed.

Comment: From background or if I dismiss the screen with the webview and open it again, the permission is not requested again

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Userdefaults` to store some flag. Once you have asked for permission set some value to that flag in the `Userdefaults`. And when your app launch check that you have set that flag or not. Something like,

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "openedOnce") {

    } else {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)")
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "openedOnce")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the app will need the permission, if I skipped it the motion detection doesn't work

Comment: I think the question should better be is there a way to always grant permission